# How to set sinusoidal velocity?

Tags: ros, velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I want my P3DX robot to have a time-varying, sinusoidal velocity as opposed to a constant velocity, how would I go about doing this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101226/how-to-set-sinusoidal-velocity?/) by [nfmoosvi](https://answers.ros.org/users/8256/nfmoosvi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Send cmd_vel messages that output a sinusoidal velocity.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3